# max Air temp for a given date NOAA

Tags: json, weather, noaa

What is the dataset id to get the maxair temp?

this is my url

```
https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND&datatypeid=temp&locationid=ZIP:90078&startdate=2017-05-01&enddate=2017-05-01"
```

my response is an empty dataset

```
    {}
```

I know my biding works because if I do this query

```
https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND&locationid=ZIP:XXXXX&startdate=2010-05-01&enddate=2010-05-01
```

where XXXXX is my zipcode I get a valid response

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, I have not been able to find any datasets for the entire contiguous US for Tmax or Tmin, but NOAA does have many land-based stations which provide Tmax and Tmin for every hour in their "Climate Data Online" database. You would search for any land-based station they have (and they have thousands around the country), and select the type of dataset you want. e.g. Hourly values, Daily values, Monthly values, etc. From there, once you select the station and dataset, you can proceed to checkout the data for free and select any of the values they have available, in which Tmax and Tmin are almost always present. You can find the CDO here: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/search?datasetid=ANNUAL

Hope this helps!!